# Data Bound Integer is Always 0

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `TextBlock` which I am binding to an `int`.  My `int` is in a separate class (`CalorieTracker`) from my `TextBlock`.  I am guessing that `CalorieTracker` is not initialized, but it should be, right?  I am so confused.  Any ideas of what I am missing here?  I am new to Windows Phone development, (and everyone is new to Windows Phone 8.1 development), but hopefully someone can shed some light!

Here is the code with my `TextBlock`:

```
        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="SECTION 1" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <HubSection.DataContext>
                <local:CalorieTracker/>
            </HubSection.DataContext>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="caloriesAvailableTextBlock" Loaded="caloriesAvailableTextBlock_Loaded" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" Text="{Binding CaloriesAvailable}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Here is my `CalorieTracker` class:

```
public class CalorieTracker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int caloriesAvailable;
    public int CaloriesAvailable
    {
        get { return caloriesAvailable; }
        set { caloriesAvailable = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CaloriesAvailable");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In my code behind for the section with my `TextBlock`, I have the property:

```
    public CalorieTracker CalorieTracker { get; set; }
```

And I initialize it in the `NavigationHelper_LoadState` method:

```
    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        CalorieTracker = new CalorieTracker();
        CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable = 2000;
    }
```

Any ideas why the `TextBlock` always shows 0?  (In my actual code, I also have a button which changes the value of `CaloriesAvailable`.)

Comment: Still did not figure out how to do it this way, but I found a work around after making some changed and thanks to some help, so anyone who may be searching for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900100/textblock-wont-update/24900153#24900153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is might be what you are refering too.

In your code you have this section:

```
        <HubSection.DataContext>
            <local:CalorieTracker/>
        </HubSection.DataContext>
```

This step actually initializes an instance of CalorieTracker and sets this instance as the DataContext of your HubSection. On top of that you have your property in CalorieTracker, CaloriesAvailable which is an int, the default value of an int is 0, so when it is initialized and you haven't set CaloriesAvailable to any specific, it uses the default value 0, this is why your Textbox displays 0. 
I hope this helps. 
Apologizes for grammer, not my strong point :P

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is by getting `CalorieTracker` object that has been set from XAML through `DataContext`, instead of creating a new `CalorieTracker` instance :

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    CalorieTracker = (CalorieTracker)HubSection1.DataContext;
    CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable = 2000;
}
```