# TextBlock Won't Update

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` (`caloriesAvailableTextBlock`) which I am trying to update.  The `Button` (`eatCaloriesButton`) is supposed to reduce the number which the `TextBlock` is bound to by 100.  However, the `TextBlock` will not update.  It just remains at 2000.  Any ideas what I am missing?

My xaml in HubPage.xaml:

```
 <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Calories Available:" FontSize="24"/>
     <TextBlock x:Name="caloriesAvailableTextBlock" Loaded="caloriesAvailableTextBlock_Loaded" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="36"/>
     <Button x:Name="eatCaloriesButton" Content="Eat 100 Calories" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="18" Click="eatCaloriesButton_Click" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

My code behind in HubPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public CalorieTracker CalorieTracker { get; set; }

    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        CalorieTracker = new CalorieTracker();
        CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable = 2000;
    }

    private void eatCaloriesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable -= 100;
    }

    private void caloriesAvailableTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBlock)sender).DataContext = CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable;
    }
```

My `CalorieTracker.cs` class which holds the number which I am updating:

```
public class CalorieTracker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int caloriesAvailable;
    public int CaloriesAvailable
    {
        get { return caloriesAvailable; }
        set { caloriesAvailable = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CaloriesAvailable");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that whenever `CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable` is changed, it will let all occurences of that variable know, but that is not what is happening.  Any idea why not?  Or am I just way off base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here appears to be how you set up your binding.

You set the **whole DataContext** to that int for your textblock. This is *not* what you want to do. For that to update on variable change, well, a lot of stuff would have to be different (for starters the runtime would have to listen on `DataContextChanged` instead of `PropertyChanged`).

Instead, set the `DataContext` for the page to your view model, then bind to a property:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="caloriesAvailableTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CaloriesAvailable}" FontSize="36"/>

private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = CalorieTracker = new CalorieTracker();
    CalorieTracker.CaloriesAvailable = 2000;
}
```

Now your `NotifyPropertyChanged` will actually do what you expected, and your UI will update. This is a much better fit for the MVVM pattern anyways.

Comment: I was searching for several hours, and you just schooled me in a matter of minutes...THANK YOU!!!!  (Your explanation actually cleared up a lot about how to use DataContext for me.)

Comment: @Evorlor One view model per view is a good rule of thumb. Glad you were able to get it working!